# How to use a closure, anonymous method, or delayed invocation while deep cloning?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a set of items that are designed tree-like with references to children. I want to deep clone the item, with one complexity that I need help with. The property `OtherFooId` holds an int that *could* match the Id of a nested `Foo` within `Foo.Children` that could be a deep child of this tree of Foos. If indeed there is a Foo somewhere in the nested tree of input Foos with a matching id, the clone's Name should take the value of the other nested Foo.

My question is that my recursive deep-cloning algorithm is likely never better than O(n) operation to visit every nested Foo and create a clone *without* the `OtherFooId` property, as it would be a 1:1 copy the `input.Name` to `clone.Name`, as per my rudimentary clone method shown.

However the `OtherFooId` property seems to need a preconstructed dictionary of `<int,Foo>` so that during the cloning recursion I have an efficient lookup each time a non-null `OtherFooId` is encountered. This would require an initial O(n) recursion visit to each nested input Foo to populate said dictionary, followed by a second O(n) recursion of constructor calls.

All that said, I thought maybe a solution exists that performs only one O(n) recursion, creates the required closures around all the values required to construct a new cloned Foo, puts the Foo in a dictionary, and delay the invocation of the constructors until the initial O(n) is complete.

It it theoretically possible to keep O(n) time complexity in this case? If so, how can I craft the required anonymous closures to make this happen?

```
class Foo
{
   List<Foo> Children {get;} = new();
   string Name {get;init;}
   int Id {get;init;}
   int? OtherFooId {get;init;}
}

// recursive method
Foo Clone(Foo input)
{
   // rudimentary: Foo clone = new(){Name = input.Name, Id = input.Id};
   // required:
   string name;
   if(input.OtherFooId is int i) // find the Foo with the matching Id, name = match.Name
   else name = input.Name;   

   Foo clone = new(){Id = input.Id, Name = name, OtherFooId = input.OtherFooId};

   foreach(Foo child in input.Children)clone.Children.Add(Clone(child));

   return clone;
}
```